# Small game menu in C# forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm supposed to create a small game menu in C#. What i'm doing now is that with each button you click in the main menu, you get a new form so it's something like this.

User clicks: Play

```
Form playMenu = new Form(); 
playMenu.Show();
this.Hide();
```

New form including buttons appears with new options to choose from.

I feel like there is a better way to do this but i have no idea how.
Something in a way of having just 1 form instead of multiple and having buttons something like this:

User clicks: Options

```
playButton.visible = false;
options.Visible = true;
```

Doing the above makes it possible to just have 1 form but wouldn't it be difficult to make changes to the buttons?
I have no idea if this is the right way to do this.

Comment: Maybe a [wizard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954037/which-wizard-control-can-i-use-in-a-winforms-application) is what you looking for?

Comment: @ckruczek It seems to me that a wizard would be more suitable for setups. I can see it's application for something like this but i'm not sure if this is what i'm looking for.

Comment: put tabsheets on your form and the nextbutton click will hide the current tabpage and show the next tabpage

Answer (score 0):

You have to design your sub-menus as `UserControl`s instead of `Form`s, put them all in a single container (`Panel`) with `Dock = DockStyle.Fill` and toggle their `Visible` or z-order (with `BringToFront` and `SendToBack` methods).

This gives you much flexibility in terms of visual layout and data flow.