# How to simulate obtaining user input sequentially using async/await in C#

Tags: c#, async-await

Suppose you need to get strings from user input. In a console application, the desired code is straightforward:

```
string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
string input2 = Console.ReadLine();
```

However, in my Windows Forms application, I’m working with a Multiline TextBox. I want to capture strings when the user presses the Enter key, with each line separated by a newline.

I’m curious if there’s an Async/Await solution that allows me to handle the KeyPressed event and return user inputs. Ideally, I’d like to achieve something like this:

```
string input1 = await GetUserInputAsync();
string input2 = await GetUserInputAsync();
```

Comment: You want to get the text from the Textbox when the user presses `Enter`? The simplest would probably be to attach a [`KeyPress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)  handler ...

Comment: @derpirscher I need to process user inputs sequentially. For example, if the first input is a specific value, I’ll get the next input.

Comment: Maybe consider not using a TextBox for this but a series of input dialogs? Some may call it a "Wizzard" - I'm not a Gui-Guy, so there surely is a more accurate term for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954144/982149 maybe interesting for you?

Comment: @Fildor I want to implement a terminal-like application, but I can’t use a console application project. After running the terminal, it will ask some questions sequentially and perform different tasks based on user inputs.

Comment: So something like a built-in interactive terminal? In that case you just upped the number of orders of complexity.

Comment: @Fildor Yes, exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a semaphore :

```
    readonly SemaphoreSlim userEnterSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async Task DoUserFlow()
    {
        // do some stuff

        // Wait semaphore
        await userEnterSemaphore.WaitAsync();

        // do some stuff

    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {
            userEnterSemaphore.Release();
        }
    }
```

Semaphore is maybe not exactly for this purpose, but it can work.
You can take a look at the AutoResetEvent too which can be very usefull.

```
// Declare the AutoResetEvent (ManualResetEvent exists too)
AutoResetEvent resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

// Wait for the event
await Task.Run(() => resetEvent.WaitOne());

// Raise the event on key pressed
if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
{
    resetEvent.Set();
}
```

ManualResetEvent can be handy in your situation, you can reset all of your events at the begining of the DoUserFlow method to be sure that any events are not already raised